# Play framework and scala Convert List<T> for Json String

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I`m trying to convert List to Json String, here is my code

```
  def getProductAsJson(txt:String):String={
                var products=new ListBuffer[Product]()


                 val conn = DB.getConnection()
                 try {
                    val stmt = conn.createStatement
                    val q="SELECT * from m_products where pro_name like '"+txt+"%' "
                    println(q);
                    val rs = stmt.executeQuery(q)
                     while (rs.next()) {
                      products+=Product(Some(rs.getInt("idproduct")),rs.getString("pro_name"),rs.getBigDecimal("pro_retprice"),
                      rs.getString("pro_description"),rs.getString("pro_brand"),rs.getString("pro_type"),rs.getString("pro_sup"),rs.getString("pro_supref"),rs.getBigDecimal("pro_supprice"),rs.getBigDecimal("pro_markup"),Some(rs.getString("pro_imgpath")),rs.getInt("pro_active"));
                    }
                } finally {
                    conn.close()
                }

                println(Json.toJson(products.toList).toString)
                return Json.toJson(products.toList).toString

           }
```

but i got this error

> No Json serializer found for type List[models.Product]. Try to
>   implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.

Comment: If you use Product class only fo creating string, you may construct Json in while loop manualy like creating Product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you implemented a `Writes` for your `models.Product`? If not, add something like this:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

implicit val productWrites = Json.writes[Product]
```

Then make sure that implicit `productWrites` is in scope where you call `Json.toJson`.

See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJsonCombinators#Writes and https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJsonInception#writes